# Not able to type input in cmd for scanner class input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this code that I am trying to run to get input from user through scanner class. And I am not able to type anything in the input console. There are no exceptions. Just the computer is waiting for input and what I type is not showing in the console.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

class DataBreach extends Exception{}

public class tictactoe{
    char[] data = new char[]{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '};
    HashMap<Integer, Character> XO = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();

    void assignplayercharacter(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true){
            String xo;
            System.out.print("Enter the player1 character(X or O):");
            while(!(scan.hasNext())){}
            xo = scan.next();
            if((xo.equals("x"))||(xo.equals("o"))||(xo.equals("X"))||(xo.equals("O"))){
                char x_o = xo.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                XO.put(1,x_o);
                x_o = ((xo.toUpperCase().equals("X"))?'O':'X');
                XO.put(2,x_o);
                break;
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    void play(int player){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true){
            int pos;
            System.out.print("Player"+player+"'s turn:");
            while(!(scan.hasNext())){}
            try{
                pos = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
                if(data[pos-1]!=' '){
                    throw new DataBreach();
                }
                data[pos-1] = XO.get(player);
                break;
            }
            catch(java.util.InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter only numbers from 1-9");
                String leftover = scan.nextLine();
            }
            catch(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("Please enter numbers only from 1-9");
            }
            catch(DataBreach e){
                System.out.println("That spot is already occupied. Please choose another spot");
            }

        }
        scan.close();
    }

    void game(){
        assignplayercharacter();
        play(1);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        tictactoe obj = new tictactoe();
        obj.game();
    }
}
```

When I run this program I am able to get input for the first method ***void assignplayercharacter*** but for the second function ***void play(int player)***. The program is running and the console is waiting for input but, when I type the character is not appearing on the console. If I comment out the first method ***void assignplayercharacter*** and just try to run the ***void play(int player)***, I am able to read input from the user.

*void assignplayercharacter()* - This function gets input and enters data into the HashMap.

*void play(int player)* - This function gets input from the user and modifies the character in char[] data array according to the input given.

P.S I am having problem only in getting input from the user.

Comment: Remove this line and try again : `scan.close();` The first one.

Comment: You should close the scanner just one time even if there are different scanner objetcs.

Comment: You shouldn't close the scanner at all. Don't close what you didn't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.util.Scanner.close()` method closes the Scanner. You can't take the input from the console if you have closed the `Scanner object`. So remove the `scan.close()` from your code and it will work like charm. Only close scanner object at the end.
[More on Scanner class and its methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line and try again : `scan.close();` The first one. 
The Scanner should closed at the end only.

PS : To make the game work, remove `break;` inside `void play(int player)` function.